# Is there a well known ASCII character meaning "edit"?

Tags: gui-design, symbols

When working with a UI that relies more on text than on icons it's common to find `+` to mean **Add**, `-` to mean **Delete/Remove** and `X` for **Close (or also Delete/Remove)**.  But is there a common character meaning **Edit**?

If using icons, a pencil seems to be the generally accepted symbol, but we're trying to minimize icon use.

Comment: For close, don't use a letter x. Use a times symbol × (&#215; as an escaped entity). It looks better.

Comment: This is an implementation problem NOT a UX problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not really.

As Tommy says, `*` often means it has *been* changed.

`r` and `w` are common technical characters in context of being readable and writable.

`>` can be used in context of a menu, or moving forward, or perhaps to 'move on' to an action but that action could be anything , so it's meaning would really not be clear other than by experimentation. In which case you might as well use `e`.

But - dare I say it, `edit` is itself not a long word...and commonly used where icons are not. eg here on SE, Wikipedia, and a brazilian other places.

Comment: I like the idea of just using edit. Dont be afraid of good old fashion, but clear, words.

Comment: Not so short in other languages, such as `bearbeiten` in German.

Comment: If you're German and you don't understand "edit" to be short for "editieren" you do not deserve to be taken into consideration when designing a user interface.

Answer (score 18):

There are some Unicode characters you could use. "Lower Right Pencil" (`&#x270E;` in HTML) or "Writing Hand" (`&#x270D;`). They look like this:

## ✎ ✍

You could try using different Unicode fonts or font sizes to make them look nicer.

Answer (score 4):

In order to indicate further detail (normally allowing edition), ellipsis `...` is used.

So I think it could work if edition is not in-place (a new window/callout tooltip is used for editing), and the ellipsis button opens the editable detail view.

Note that, although it is not a single character in ASCII, it is an Unicode character (U+2026) and an HTML entity (`&hellip;`).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a standard character for it. Maybe you could use an asterisk. It's already kind of used in this context: when you open a document in a lot of Windows applications, they put an asterisk after the file name, if it has unsaved changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit dated but here it goes.

EDIT is sort of a broad use item that has different application

- ie a graphic (cut and paste)
- a list (insert, change, and move)
- some text data (find replace, spell check, font properties)

That's just to name a few. My experience comes a little bit from hardware as in the audio recording/editing industry where buttons have symbols

- play   ascii(62)  '>'
- stop   ascii(254) '■'
- Rec    ascii(250) '·' but in a much larger size
- edit   ascii(94)  '^'

but if your developing for windows and you just want to use single characters
you might experiment with Symbol and wingding fonts

good luck